# Проблема при проектировании БД MSSQL

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой при проектировании БД. Возникает т.н цикличная связь.
  Для информации: предметная область - ФГОС 3 поколения, проектируемая бд должна обеспечивать ввод и хранение итоговых оценок выпускников вуза по дисциплинам и отображать сведения об успеваемости по компетенциям. 
[image: схема данных]
Суть в следующем: Есть специальность(speciality) для которой характерен набор дисциплин(descipline) они связанны отношением многие ко многим и набор компетенций (competention), компетенции характерны для одной специальности  т.е. одна специальность включает в себя несколько компетенций. Далее самый цирк, компетенции состоят из нескольких дисциплин, и одна дисциплина входит в несколько компетенций в рамках компетенции диспиплина имеет свой вес поле (weigth)  в таблице (competention_discipline). *Так же в рамках специальности у каждой дисциплины определённое общее количество часов, (я думаю это поле (total_hours) в таблице discipline_speciality* )

Прошу помощь в следующем:

1. Корректна ли данная связь в рамках данной базы (cм. рисунок) ? (Поясните свое
   мнение)
2. Поле общее количество часов на дисциплину необходимо хранить в той таблице(см. курсив выше)?

Comment: Прикалываетесь что ли? Ни фига же не видно даже при 1000% увеличения.

Comment: @Sergey, [исходник на гугле](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/RXLOffCNg6ks31K1ulcDDyiOJ23HtMmviXpic2p0GjnxjcpUfT9Jd_LG5SY5utiYZMBNXeotdhdBhutPVY1XG3-gVckiSC0)

Comment: В рамках базы допустимы любые связи, в том числе и циклические, если надо. А по описанию сути я никакой цикличности не увидел. Специальность -> Дисциплина, Специальность -> Компетенция, Компетенция -> Дисциплина. Три ветки - три тупика.Вы же не собираетесь ходить по кругу Специальность -> Дисциплина -> Компетенция -> Дисциплина -> Специальность -> ...?